# compile meshlab full for osx fails

Tags: macos, meshlab

as i can not find any precompiled version of the 2017.3 i try to compile meshlab on my mac... 
Compiled already the librarys but now i am stucked at the .full :

```
meshlabdocumentxml.cpp:115:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'opt'; did you mean 'oct'?
```

can someone give me any hint how to fix this? i am on High Sierra and QT 5.10.1 (installed with brew)
The only point in the readme which i don't find how to do or check is:

> ...be sure to select additional packages "script" and "xmlpatterns"

so maybe this is due to missing some of these? how can i find out if they are installed?

thanx in advance!
bigcheese

Comment: Have you tried `brew cask install meshlab`?

Comment: tried now, but this pulls only same version: ==> Downloading https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases/download/v2016.12/MeshLab2016.12.dmg

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a freshly compiled version of meshlab for osx just get the travis continuous builds:

- https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases  (dmg for OSX)
- https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cignoni/meshlab/build/artifacts (portable zip for win)

BTW the travis and appveyor scripts are the most accurate documentation on how to build meshlab :)